# wkhtmltopdf on Fedora 14

Tags: compilation, fedora, wkhtmltopdf

Did anybody ever installed wkhtmltopdf on Fedora 14?

On http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation there is a step by step for Debian. In the comments, there is also something similar to CentOS.

Till now I have installed:

- Development Tools
- openssl-devel libXrender-devel libXext-devel libXft-devel
- QT (qt.x86_64 qt-devel.x86_64 qt-webkit.x86_64)
- git

And I have also downloaded wkhtmltopdf from git:

```
git clone git://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf.git wkhtmltopdf
```

However, the last steps are driving me crazy. Here's where So I need some help:

- Compiling and installing wkhtmltopdf Now all you need to do is compile and install wkhtmltopdf

  make && make install

Here's the wkhtmltopdf folder:

[image]

NEW UPDATE:

After running `cd wkhtmltopdf && qmake-qt4 && make` as *normal* user, here's what I got:

[image]

Then, I searched again for some qt packages I should have and ended with this group:

`qt-webkit-devel.x86_64 php-qt-devel.x86_64 qt-x11.x86_64 qtnx.x86_64`

Then, again, I ran `qmake-qt4 && make` and this time it passed with no errors.

Finally, I ran `sudo make install` and it also passed with no errors.

However, when I ran `wkhtmltopdf -h` it returns:

`wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libwkhtmltox.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So, I decided to go all way compiling QT, following exactly the instructions. At the end, I got the same error:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -h
wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libwkhtmltox.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the part where you have to run `qmake`.

Comment: I guess you mean this: You must now run qmake in the wkhtmltopdf folder. `cd wkhtmltopdf` and `qmake-qt4`?

Comment: Then you missed part of Qt. Install `qt-devel`. And don't use `sudo` to build.

Comment: Okay. I am doing now with root user. This is what I got after running `make && make install` : /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:9:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.

Comment: About `qt-devel`: Package 1:qt-devel-4.7.2-8.fc14.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: That's part of `glibc-devel`; make sure you've installed the appropriate version for your architecture. And don't build as root.

Comment: Okay, glibc-devel.x86_64 installed. New error: `../lib/multipageloader.hh:32:20: fatal error: QWebPage: No such file or directory`. I updated the screenshot above...

Answer (score 4):

`wkhtmltopdf` want `libwkhtmltox.so.0 lib`. But search it into `/lib64` directory.
You can :

```
cd /lib64
ln -s /lib/libwkhtmltox.so.0 libwkhtmltox.so.0

wkhtmltopdf -h
```

is ok after that.

(sorry for my english...)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /lib64
ln -s /lib/libwkhtmltox.so.0 libwkhtmltox.so.0
```

This also worked on CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

The error :

```
wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libwkhtmltox.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

can also be caused by the miss of Xorg, then you can install it for example on Debian :

```
apt-get install xorg
```